# Is there any official documentation specifying that ~ (tilde) resolves to node_modules/ in Angular scss import paths?

Tags: angular, webpack, import, sass, tilde-expansion

When using a tilde (`~`) in scss import paths, it expands to `node_modules/` in Angular. Is there any piece of official documentation that says that this is a feature of either Angular or webpack?

All I have found on the matter so far is a few bug reports for previous angular versions saying it's broken, and a comment saying it's [an implementation detail that shouldn't be relied upon](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11256#issuecomment-398061428).

I was hoping to do an [`ng eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) and check the configs, but that command is no longer available.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me to either some official piece of documentation stating that `~` is shorthand for the path to `node_modules/`, or a piece of source code (e.g. a config file) that specifies that replacement. :)

Basically, I want to figure out why this works, and how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a feature of WebPack. Tilde resolving is handled by the [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) plugin for Webpack. I believe the benefits of this feature is to *import* resources such as fonts, images, etc.. into your CSS files directly from your WebPack bundles. Therefore, it has to support the same syntax for resolving WebPack paths.

It is implemented in the `importsToResolve.js` file.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/aa9b53b4d1c14117c4ca114a13cecb6e53b4e87a/src/importsToResolve.js#L12

It's a great feature, but introduces problems when you want to share SASS files between WebPack and non-Webpack projects, because [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) does not support this feature.

Comment: Thank you! The functionality is also explicitly mentioned in [the docs, section Resolving import at-rules](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#resolving-import-at-rules). Bliss! :)